# how to switch/choose between html forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a little problem, and an need your profesisonal...

So i have two forms in two div. `DIV ID=A and DIV ID=B`

When a user visit my site, a would like to offer the visitor to choose between the forms. he user see a drop down box, or two radio button, and if select option A then form A load, if B...then B..

But i don't know how to do this, and what is the best practise to do this? May i use simple html, and after choose redirect to a subpage like formA.php and formB.php? Or use Jquery and simple hide and show the needed div?

What do ya suggest? And how im a do that?

Than you.

Comment: @offtopic: If you give someone a negative vote, it's because he is doing something wrong, might be usefull if you tell him why aswell.

Comment: i dont really understand what you talkin' about..but thanks for the - vote..

Comment: you misunderstand. someone down voted your post withot explaining why. the comment isn't directed at you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery or similiar would be the most elegant imo. something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hide the forms when page is ready
    $('#a').hide();
    $('#b').hide();

    $('#button1').click(function(){ 
        $('#a').show(); 
    });
    $('#button2').click(function(){ 
        $('#b').show(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

hide the forms, have 2 buttons (can be styled divs),. then when they are clicked, show the respective HTML form.

could be extended to "toggle" the forms, or only allow 1 to be selected.

problems may occur if JS is disabled however (both forms will be visible)

Comment: hmm..nice..but if JS disabled, not so elegant. Do you know any solution if no JS then what should i do? Maybee i should check JS, and if disabled then redirect an alternative page? What do you think?

Comment: i (believe) the only way to check for JS is with JS enabled so that approach won't work quite so well. i guess <noscript> could be used but then you'll have multiple pages for the same form - getting messy and hard to maintain

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use a drop down to select the correct form. Here's an example

```
<!-- Forms HTML -->
<div id="form-A">
    ... html form here ....
</div>
<div id="form-B">
    ... another html form here ....
</div>

<!-- Hide forms initially with Javascript (visible for non Javascript users) -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form-A, #form-B").hide();
</script>

<!-- A dropdown to select a value -->
<select id="choose-form">
    <option>Please choose...</option>
    <option value="form-A">Some form</option>
    <option value="form-B">Another form</option>
</select>

<!-- and some simple jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#choose-form").change(function() {

            //Hide -other- visible forms
            $("#form-A, #form-B").hide();
            $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [.animate()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp)

```js
$('.message a').click(function() {
  $('form').animate({
    height: "toggle",
    opacity: "toggle"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form .btn {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form button:hover,
.form button:active,
.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}

.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}

.infoo {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.infoo h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

.infoo span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.infoo span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.infoo span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="login_page" class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form id="register_form" class="register-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="email address" />
      <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign up" />
      <p class="message">
        Already registered?
        <a href="#">Sign In</a>
      </p>
    </form>
    <form id="login_form" action="#" method="POST" class="login-form">
      <input name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="username" />
      <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
      <input id="btnLg" type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign in" />
      <p class="message">
        Not registered?
        <a href="#">Create an account</a>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery as described by Ross then as you suggest yourself, if Javascript is turned off redirect them according to their choice.