# Change to different form on drop down menu selection

Tags: php, forms

I have an apparel ordering form on a page. I want to "swap-out" that form with another one when I select an option from a drop-down list/menu. Ajax maybe? PHP include()? The options in the drop-down would select different forms already created as templates in another directory and render it in place of the other form.

I just want one form showing at a time. Thanks! :)

Comment: My be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675006/how-to-switch-choose-between-html-forms

Comment: @AshkayP Thanks, I saw that one and am testing it, but would that way work for 20 forms? 50 forms? We have many styles. Is there any problem with having that many forms hidden on one page?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put too many hidden forms if you can. It's just bad design, especially regarding performance. Your best bet is to:

- Create some PHP files with a form inside each
- Use an **AJAX request** to communicate if the condition is met

If you like stuffing up things in one file try passing **a unique parameter** with AJAX to the PHP file and **check its value to decide which form to load**.

**Example**:

```
var xhr = new XMLhttpRequest();
    formID = (condition) ? 1 : 2; // etc

    //^^ This one line above means:
    if (condition) {
        formID = 1;
    }
    else {
        formID = 2;
    }

...

// GET request
xhr.open("GET", "forms.php?formID=" + formID);

// POST request
xhr.send("formID=" + formID);
```

**In PHP**:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["formID"]) && $_POST["formID"] === 1):
?>
        <form id = "1"></form>
<?php
    else:
?>
        <form id = "2"></form>
<?php
    endif;
?>
```

**[EDIT]**:

If you want to have each form in a different file then the above code will be:

```
<form>...</form> // No PHP necessary
```

In JavaScript use `xhttp.send("")` without putting any values (*only if the forms are in different files*).

Comment: I am a bit of a beginner, so your code is a little vague to me. Are you saying I can create a template for each form and use AJAX to render any chosen one onto the page?

Comment: Exactly. Create your two forms and put them inside the `if statement` as I did in order for PHP to decide which one to render. PHP will decide which one to render based on the data you send to it with the AJAX request. It can be anything really, but I used the numbers `1` and `2` for simplicity.

Comment: Also, in case you don't know yet, `isset()` check if something exists. So `if isset($_POST["formID"])` checks if PHP received the data from AJAX. Then we check its value so as to decide which form to display.

Comment: Do I need to have the " && $_POST["formID"] " in there?

Comment: **Yes** _(in case all your forms are in the same file, otherwise, **no**)_. You need it to see if the value you send with AJAX is the one that corresponds to the form you want to display. I also corrected my edit, because it was not clear.